# Problems using a package in conda

Tags: installation, conda, bioinformatics

I am new to using Linux/coding etc. and I've been installing packages using conda and most have been fine. I installed Medaka using

`conda create -n medaka -c conda-forge -c bioconda medaka`

But if I try and execute it says 'command not found'

I know the medaka environment is there, but if I list what's in conda, it's not there as a package (even though if I physically look in the folder it exists. I tried reinstalling, but can't because the environment exists and tried updating but get an error:

> PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix

I also can't seem to remove or delete the environment. It seems a bit of a catch 22! If anyone could help I'd be most appreciative!

Comment: Please edit the question to include the commands you try to run. E.g., `medaka_consensus` or `medaka_variant`.

Comment: Have you tried `conda update --all`. Could you try it and see if the error still exists?